# Migrate to non-transitive R-Classes issue with navigation arguments

Tags: android

I just migrated to non-transitive R-Classes in an Android project and I'm getting a compilation error in a generated class regarding navigation!

```
<argument
        android:name="title"
        android:defaultValue="@string/myString"
        app:argType="reference" />

public data class NavGraphLocationSelectionArgs(
  public val isAddDeviceEnabled: Boolean = false,
  public val title: Int = R.string.myString,
) : NavArgs {
```

Unresolved reference: string

Any ideas? I cleaned, built many times, when I remove android:defaultValue="@string/myString" it works. It also works when I set android.nonTransitiveRClass=false of course.

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am getting this same error where the resource references  in classes generated by safeargs plugin are not prepended with the appropriate package name of the module where the nav assets are located, and so fail when I set nonTransitiveRClass to true. This happens with version 2.7.7 and also 2.8.0-alpha04

Comment: @nwagu - did you [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757)? Can you include a link to it?

Comment: Oh never mind, I found what was wrong with my code